# how to handle byte-like values with Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7

I am trying to make a Python 2 code compatible with and Python 3. I am using `python-ldap`. In Python 3 the values of the queried attributes of the objects are returned as byte-like objects:

```
[('CN=user,CN=Users,DC=excample,DC=com', {'displayName': [b'Test User'], 'objectSid': [b'\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x15\x00\x00\x00\xa0e\xcf~xK\x9b_\xe7|\x87p\t\x1c\x01\x00'], 'sAMAccountName': [b'user'], 'pwdLastSet': [b'132144982087435710'], 'whenChanged': [b'20191020171614.0Z']})]
```

```
for item in data:
    for key, value in item[1].items():
       print(value[0])
       print(type(value[0]))
```

And I get:

```
b'Test User'
<class 'bytes'>
b'\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x15\x00\x00\x00\xa0e\xcf~xK\x9b_\xe7|\x87p\t\x1c\x01\x00'
<class 'bytes'>
b'user'
<class 'bytes'>
b'132144982087435710'
<class 'bytes'>
b'20191020171614.0Z'
<class 'bytes'>
```

In Python 2:

```
[('CN=user,CN=Users,DC=excample,DC=com', {'displayName': ['Test User'], 'objectSid': ['\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x15\x00\x00\x00\xa0e\xcf~xK\x9b_\xe7|\x87p\t\x1c\x01\x00'], 'sAMAccountName': ['user'], 'pwdLastSet': ['132144982087435710'], 'whenChanged': ['20191020171614.0Z']})]
```

and with the loop:

```
for item in data:
    for key, value in item[1].items():
       print(value[0])
       print(type(value[0]))
```

I get:

```
132144982087435710
<type 'str'>
e���J=��}e�O
<type 'str'>
Test User
<type 'str'>
user
<type 'str'>
20191020171614.0Z
<type 'str'>
```

So I cannot make any string operations and keep get the following:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

or with `time()` methods:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>
```

I went through [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/pyporting.html), but I cannot get it work. `decode()` wont help, firstly the `objectSid` is a specific combination of `hex` and `big-endian` and `little-endian`, so it must be decoded in a different way, for which I already have wrote function. Secondly I need the data as byte-like objects as well.
In Python 2 that wasn't an issue, since I could do byte-like objects operation as well as string and list operation.

Thanks

Comment: Making Python code cross-compatible between v2 and v3 without something like `six` is challenging and frustrating. Is there a particular reason you are not using an existing cross-version framework?

Comment: Not at all. I'll be glad if I could handle this with `six`. I don't know if `six` will be helpful here?